# Где запускать php код на Mac m1?

Tags: php, macos

Есть ли какие-то способы запустить php код на маке с M1 кроме homebrew?

Comment: Чем вам homebrew не угодил?

Comment: Много пишут, что он загрязняет систему

Comment: Ну скачай тогда сырцы с офсайта и собирай.

Comment: Что качать и собирать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать установить программные пакеты, такие как MAMP или XAMPP (для Mac).

MAMP: https://www.mamp.info

XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/download_success.html

Мне лично нравится MAMP pro, это платное программное обеспечение, но вы можете установить пробную версию, также есть бесплатная версия, которая называется MAMP.

Comment: mamp это конечно хорошо, но платить за него от 80 до 100 евро? серьезно?

Comment: @KoVadim никто и никогда не помешает Вам взять свой пиратский фрегат и отправиться бороздить моря в поисках Крякена.

Comment: зачем пиратский? я не понимаю, зачем вообще устанавливать такой софт, когда это все абсолютно доступно без какой то оплаты (ещё раз для тех кто в танке, я не говорю о взломанном софте, апач, nginx, php, mysql давно-давно можно взять с исходным кодом без какой то оплаты)

Comment: между тем, ссылка на xampp немного ведет не туда:)